# Unable to create an Entitlement Management Catalog in Azure AD - Identity Governance

Tags: azure-active-directory, entitlements

I am unable to create an Entitlement Management Catalog in Azure AD - Identity Governance.

There is a validation check on the "Name" field which keeps spinning endlessly. If I hover over the spinning animation, I get the hint "Catalog with the same name already exists.". However, I don't have any catalogs in my Azure AD instance. And if the name is globally unique, the hint message is not accurate because I've tried impossibly unique names and still getting the same issue.

I am not sure if the hint is simply misleading and there is another issue I need to take a look at or if this is a bug of some sort.

My Azure AD instance is Free which is sufficient for creating catalogs as per this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/education/deploy/design-identity-governance (License Requirements section).

I also have the "Global Administrator" and "Identity Governance Administrator" roles assigned to my user account.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error with other community members, it turns out that you do in fact need Azure AD Premium P2 license to do ANYTHING with catalogs, access reviews, etc. The "[License requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/education/deploy/design-identity-governance#license-requirements)" is not entirely accurate where it says P2 is not required for Global Administrators who set up the initial catalogs, access packages, and policies, and delegate administrative tasks to other users.

Answer (score 0):

I have one Azure AD instance with **`Free`** license like below:

[image]

Now, I assigned same **roles** as you to one user named **`Sri`** like below:

[image]

When I signed in with above user account, I'm able to **create catalog** successfully like below:

[image]

But when I tried to create another catalog with existing catalog name, I got **same error** as you like this:

[image]

In your case, check whether you selected **Select All** under `Enabled` and `Enabled for external users` or not to see all existing catalogs.

Alternatively, make use of below **PowerShell** script to create catalog if there is any issue with your Portal:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "EntitlementManagement.ReadWrite.All"
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"

New-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackageCatalog -DisplayName "DeviCatalog" -Description "Created from PowerShell"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, catalog created successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sri, I checked all of that before I made the post. I have the same roles, and I tried the PowerShell command. Here is the error I get in PowerShell "New-MgEntitlementManagementAccessPackageCatalog_CreateExpanded: Unable to find target address". Researching the error, I think the issue perhaps my Azure Account created using MSA account and this article states that the Graph API doesn't support MSA accounts https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/891434/unable-to-find-target-address-error-while-using-mi

Comment: Instead of MSA account, try creating one local **Azure AD user account** (ends with .onmicrosoft.com) by assigning same directory roles and try creating catalog by signing in with new user account.

Comment: Hi @Sridevi , I tried that and it didn't work. I assigned the user "Global Administrator" role (even though shouldn't be needed because next role is sufficient) and "Identity Governance Administrator" role. This time, this new user doesn't even have permissions to see the "Catalogs". I get a "No Access" error code 403. Content "CatalogListBlade", Extension "Microsoft_Azure_ELMAdmin", Resource ID "Not Available". This doesn't make sense especially of the roles granted for this user.

Comment: Note that, it will take some amount of time(upto 24 hrs Max) to reflect after assigning Azure AD directory roles. So, it won't work as soon as assigning the roles. Could you try to do create catalog again now and check?

Comment: I just tried using the Azure AD created identity (not the MSA) and I got the same result. The same error in my previous comment (No access basically) and same issue with MSA account (spins forever complaining about the catalog name). I've also cleared cache and cookies being paranoid at this point that you seem to have no issues on your end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Azure AD Premium P2 license in order to create a Catalog in Azure AD Identity Governance. Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/education/deploy/design-identity-governance#license-requirements) link for clarity.

Comment: That's the same link in my post. Under "License requirements" section. It says "Azure AD Premium P2 licenses are **not** required for the following tasks:" and then it proceeds to by saying in the first bulletin "Users with the Global Administrator role who set up the initial catalogs, access packages, and policies, and delegate administrative tasks to other users." and that's what I have. However, I found out a while that you are right and that you do need P2 license, it's just the documentation is not accurate.